# How to get Google Sign-In for Websites to work with Identity Aware Proxy

Tags: google-signin, google-identity, google-iap

I have a web site in google cloud. I use Identity-Aware Proxy (IAP) to protect it.

When a request comes in IAP checks if I'm authorized and then responds with either

- if I'm authorized: the response from the resource I requested
- if not: a 302 or 401 response depending on if it thinks it is an ajax call or not

Now I want to use [Google Sign-In for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) on top of this.

This might seem redundant since I am already logged in by the time I would see the buttons but I want to use it as a way to log out or change user account.

Now what I have tried to do is:

```
var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
  client_id: 'mykey.apps.googleusercontent.com',
})

auth2.isSignedIn.get()
// false, I was hoping that I could somehow piggyback on my existing session

auth2.signIn()
// shows a pop up, allowing me to select an account

auth2.isSignedIn.get()
// true

currentUser.getBasicProfile()
// works
```

This seems to work except it shows me a login box even when I'm already logged in which is suspicious.

Add to this that when I do

```
auth2.disconnect()

auth2.isSignedIn.get()
// false
```

and then do a full refresh then I still get my resources from IAP proving that I'm still logged in there.

Questions:

- How can I get this to work?
- Is this even the correct way to do it?

Comment: I know it's been a while but did you ever get this to work?
I'm getting a 401

Comment: @Dandan I'm not working on that project anymore and IIRC it wasn't fixed last time I checked. If you create a new question that only asks about that particular question and ping me I'll still be interested in following it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about Sign-In for Websites, but there's another option that might work for you. Have you considered adding a link to /_gcp_iap/clear_login_cookie to provide a "change user account" option?  (It's documented here: https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/special-urls-howto )

If the user is logged in with multiple Google accounts, that will bounce them back to the account picker.  Today, if they're only logged in with one account, it will just send them right back into the application -- but there's an enhancement rolling out next week which will display the account picker even for the single-account case, giving the user a chance to sign in with an additional account.

Hope that helps!
  --Matthew, IAP engineering lead

Comment: Definitely tried. FWIW when I googled this thoroughly a few weeks ago there only seemed to be one single page on the entire internet for the search term "_gcp_iap/identity" (I wondered if this was a bug with google search engine but ddg also returns only one relevant page : )

Comment: Also thanks a lot for fixing the bug you mentioned: I know that one has been a pain in certain circumstances.

Comment: Update: The fix missed our last pre-Thanksgiving rollout, so expect it late Nov / early Dec.